# How do I change part of a parent class's constructor when inheriting from it?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I've got some class and I want to make an object out of it. However, this class has a property set in its constructor that makes it unusable for me.  I cannot edit this class's code as it exists in a very tight codebase.  This property cannot be changed after the object is constructed, so even if there WERE a setter method, it wouldn't work (it's part of the SWT gui framework, and can't be changed dynamically).

My instinct tells me to subclass it and change what I need to change.  Should only take a few lines because every other aspect of this class will stay the same.  However, since the first line you need to call in a child class's constructor is the super method, that means the parent class's constructor is called before I can even do anything.

Is there ANY way I can make an object out of this class with just ONE small property changed, without having to create an entire new class that's a copy/paste of all its code, except for one small change in like 8?

Thanks!

EDIT: since someone requested code:

```
public class Parent {
    private Object important_object = null;
    public Parent() {
        important_object = new Object();
        important_object.important_property = BAD;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
           // how the heck do I make an instance of this
           // class that has important_property set to GOOD
           // instead of BAD?
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be much easier for us to understand your question if you post the code instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: The code is hundreds of lines long, but I will try to create a psuedo implementation for you of the parts that matter.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...what is the exact reason for changing the value? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I agree with @copeg sine you may break some conditions the (original) class depends on. If you incist on changing the attribute, you could try [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to change the attribute you need to change.

Comment: @Turing85: I do not think the environment I'm in would be too receptive of the use of reflection... (also, code is now up in update)

Comment: If you can't use reflection you can't cange the value of that field in a subclass.

Comment: @user1903064 then you are out of luck. If there is no way to access the `important_object`, you cannot change it.

Comment: thanks Turing85.  @copeg Seeing as the property needs to be changed I don't think this is a valid XY problem because I proposed no solution and there is no alternative to changing that property -- it must be done.

Comment: Thanks. for those interested, the parent is a custom SWT control with lots of good logic, EXCEPT its style is set to read_only.  No way to change styles after the fact with SWT, according to Google.  Unless this IS an XY problem and I just can't see how else to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attribute is `private`, no setter to either `important_object` or `important_property` is provided and you cannot use [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) then there is no way to change the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called classworking, that allows you to modify the Java bytecode in runtime, but it's definitely non-trivial and it probably is way too much for this. Although it's a very interesting read.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-cwt02076/

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

Comment: If reflection is not permitted, then I'm not seeing this getting approved either.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree, however I thought that if OP really wanted to know he might have found the technique interesting.

Comment: thanks for the technique, @Acapulco.  This is against the rules as well but it's good to know about :)